# How to change image in UIImageView with UISlider in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uislider

I'm trying to use the UISlider to change images in UIImageView
So the idea is that if the slider value is 1, a certain image shows if it's 2, different image shows. etc.

Can someone please help?

Edit: This is the code I tried. I think it's supposed to be an If/Else statement but I'm not sure how to form the syntax.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scaleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scaleSlider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var scaleImage: UIImageView!



@IBAction func valueChanged1(sender: AnyObject) {

    if scaleSlider.value == 1 {
        scaleImage.image = "Image.png"
    }

}
```

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I edited my post. I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: whats ur minimum and maximum value of slider

Comment: So what's the problem? Swift syntax? The image bit (you're trying to assign a string to a UIImage)? Something else?

Comment: The minimum is 0 and maximum is 10.
@ Anbu, yes it is giving me that error of assigning a string to UIImage.

Comment: `scaleImage.image = "Image.png"`  that's shouldn't be working. You should use `UIImage(imageNamed:)` or something similar. What you could do, put all images names in an array, then according to its values, get the name at that index, and change the image.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

do like

```
@IBAction func valueChanged1(_ sender: UISlider) {

 var imageName : String = "Image.png"

 switch (sender.value)
{
  case 0:
    print("zero")
  imageName = "yyyy.png"

  case 1:
    print("one")
  imageName = "zzzz.png"
  case 2:
    print("two")
   imageName = "aaaa.png"

  default:
    print("Integer out of range")
 }

  if let image = UIImage(named:imageName) {
    scaleImage.image = image
   }

}
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthnik Not the best solution since you ignore any non-integer values, aren't you? So if user skips expected value, image will stay unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array of filenames.
2. Convert your slider value to an int.
3. Use that int to index into the array of filenames.
4. Use `image(named:)` to load the image with that name.
5. Install the image into your image view.

See if you can convert those steps to code. If not edit your question to show your code and tell us what happens and we'll show you how to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Since slider has a Float value and you need an integer value to pick image from array, I assume that you want to use the closest integer index for current value of the slider:

```
let images = [
    UIImage(named: "image1"),
    UIImage(named: "image2"),
    UIImage(named: "image3")
]

var currentIndex = 0 {
    didSet {
        if oldValue != currentIndex {
            currentIndexUpdated()
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    currentIndex = Int(round(sender.value))
}

func currentIndexUpdated() {
    guard 0..<images.count ~= currentIndex else { return }
    imageView.image = images[currentIndex]
}
```